# MYSQL check for duplicate c++

Tags: c++, mysql

I am developing WIN32 application using VS 2019.
data insertion to MYSQL database is working fine.
But Before inserting the data i need to check for duplication.
Here is my code for Name duplication check In Product Table in MYSQL.

```
int nQueryState = 0;
MYSQL conn;

nQueryState = mysql_query(&conn, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.Name = 'Paneer 200gm');");

if(nQueryState>0)
    MessageBox(NULL, "Match found !!", "My first Gui", MB_OK);
else
    MessageBox(NULL, "No Match found !!", "My first Gui", MB_OK);
```

Please help me out whats wrong with my code..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the issue exactly? Do you get an error?

Comment: What is the problem with your code? Your outer query is probably unnecessary, the inner query with a limit of 1 would probably be sufficient

Comment: Don't check for duplicates, declare unique indexes and catch errors. Any prechecking will result in a race condition of an insert being possible. Your application may control enough of the space to prevent this, however its a good practice to get into.

Comment: I am not getting error but getting same result if match or No match

Comment: I don't know c++ , but this looks nothing like the example in the manual for connecting to MySQL from c++

Comment: @Mayur `mysql_query` returns 0 if the query succeeds, but you don't test if there are rows. The query can succeed and have no rows. @danblack gives good advice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.Name = 'Paneer 200gm')
```

Is exactly:

```
SELECT * FROM product WHERE product.Name = 'Paneer 200gm'
```

So when writing queries keep it simple.

On the comment above, it looks like you want the product name to be unique.

```
 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_name ON product(Name)
```

If you insert a duplicate here you will get an error. So check the query results on your `INSERT` statement and you'll see a duplicate key error. This has a distinct code where you can process with `MessageBox`.